# cron job that is executing every 9 minutes on Hangfire not wokring

Tags: c#, cron, hangfire

I am new to cron expression. All i need to know that how to create cron for the recurring job in Hangfire.Im using c#  that executes every 9 minutes after job started.No need to start  0 th time. I've tried exploring cron expression  */9 * * * *.
but its not executed properly,it runs in every 4 or 5 minute

```
public void offlinecheck (string id) {
            Console.WriteLine("job started "+DateTime.Now);
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate (id+"offlinecheck", () =>dbofflinecheck(id),"*/9 * * * *"); //9mnt
        }
public void dbofflinecheck (string id) {
            Console.WriteLine("job run "+DateTime.Now + " " + id);}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code here? It you help other users to help you.

Comment: sorry .now i added code